# Why does this bool not work in a custom function, but works fine in the update function?

Tags: c#, function, unity-game-engine, boolean

I'm trying to check if an object (obj_a) has reached a certain distance away from another object (obj_b), and then to turn a bool to true, move the object (obj_a) to the other object (obj_b), and change the bool back to false.

I'm trying to do this in my own function to avoid the spaghetti code I had, but **now that it's in my own function the bool is permanently stuck on false**.

I've tried the same code outside of a function and it has worked fine, I just want it inside one so I can make it more modular and add more objects easily, and edit it more easily

heres my code:

```
public GameObject obj_a, obj_b;
public GameObject obj_c, obj_d;
public float specifiedDistance = 5.0f;
private bool bool1 = false; // initialize as false because they start within the distance
private bool bool2 = false;

// custom function to be called in Update()
void checkTargets(GameObject _a, GameObject _b, bool _bool)
{
  Vector3 dist = _a.transform.position - _b.transform.position;
  if(dist.magnitude > specifiedDistance)
{
  _bool = true;
}
  if(_a.transform.position == _b.transform.position)
{
  _bool = false;
}

void Update()
{
  checkTargets(obj_a, obj_b, bool1);
  checkTargets(obj_c, obj_d, bool2);
}
```

Comment: If you use the bools outside of the checkTargets scope you probably need to set global variables instead of local variables. So instead of setitng _bool you need to set bool1 or bool2.

Comment: ohhh, I thought because I used the global variables in update that it would output the local _bool to bool1 and 2, does that mean that it's just updating _bool and thats why bool1 and bool2 arent being updated?

Comment: You could simplify with bool value = Vector3.Distance(a.tranform.position, b.transform.position)  > specifiedDistance; also the equal check is likely yo never happen due to float inaccuracy over 3 values. You'd be better off checking if the distance is less than a small enough value.

Comment: Though you have a global _bool, the local one prevails,  the one as parameter. Some IDE would warn of that possible unwanted behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C# passes method arguments by value by default. For value types, such as `bool`, this means that the method parameter `_bool` and the passed field `bool1` are stored in separate locations in memory. Therefore, you do not modify the value of `bool1` by modifying `_bool` inside the method.

The simplest way to fix this in your case is to return the boolean value from the method instead:

```
bool1 = checkTargets(obj_a, obj_b);
bool2 = checkTargets(obj_c, obj_d);

bool checkTargets(GameObject _a, GameObject _b)
{
  Vector3 dist = _a.transform.position - _b.transform.position;
  if(dist.magnitude > specifiedDistance)
  {
    return true;
  }
  if(_a.transform.position == _b.transform.position)
  {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! this has fixed my problem of the bools staying false, but I realised that in my code, when I move the object it moves TO the specified distance, instead of moving to the object once it has reached that distance.

in my previous version of this code I had if(dist.magnitude > specifiedDistance && bool1==false){etc.} is there a way I could do this with this method?

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you are passing argument `_bool` as a **value** when it should be passed as a [**reference**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref).

Edit: But doing like [the other answerer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63992862/13238535) suggests is probably better in terms of readability and maintainabilty because you clearly write what is assigned to what. And you have a pure function.

Answer (score 0):

I also think this answer [is a smarter solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63992862/10635657).
For the time being, specify how to pass the value by reference.

```
public GameObject obj_a, obj_b;
public GameObject obj_c, obj_d;
public float specifiedDistance = 5.0f;
private bool bool1 = false; // initialize as false because they start within the distance
private bool bool2 = false;

// custom function to be called in Update()
void checkTargets(GameObject _a, GameObject _b, ref bool _bool)
{
    Vector3 dist = _a.transform.position - _b.transform.position;

    if(dist.magnitude > specifiedDistance)
    {
        _bool = true;
    }

    if(_a.transform.position == _b.transform.position)
    {
        _bool = false;
    }
}

void Update()
{
    checkTargets(obj_a, obj_b,ref bool1);
    checkTargets(obj_c, obj_d,ref bool2);
}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer! this one worked perfectly, the other answer explained my issue  but I found out I had to reference the global bools within checkTargets() to get my objects to move correctly, so I couldnt use that method